# microsoft sql server 2005 restoring .bak file

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a database hosted however the hosting expired. Need to restore my .bak file.

Does the .bak file include the tables/procedures or only the data?

How do I restore .bak file?

Thanks

Comment: Have you got access to the SQL management tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .bak file should have everything of the database it was made from - tables, sprocs and data.

To restore it, right-click the `Databases` folder in the Object Explorer  and choose `Restore Database`.
Type in a name you wish to use for the restored database in the `To database:` field.
Then select the `From device:` radio button and press the `...` button to select your .bak file: in the window that appears press the `Add` button and select the correct file, then press `OK`.

Comment: which application is this? I am using Visual Studio to code my web application.   Thanks

Comment: This is SQL Server Management Studio, which comes with the SQL Server installer but not with Visual Studio.